# SQL Server 2014 Express Client Not Connecting

Tags: sql-server

This is a new SQL Server 2014 Express installation. 
The application using the SQL Server, installed on the server works, no problem connecting.
But when a client PC (on the LAN) tries to use the application, the "canned" SQL Server message says that "server does not exist or connection denied".
I think that the SQL Server is not listening on port 1433 but can't figure out why not.  Here is what I tried:

1. Server Connection property has the box "*Allow remove connections to this computer is checked*"
2. SQL Server Browser is running.
3. SQL Server *Configuration Manager -> Client Protocols -> TCP/IP: Port 1433* is enabled.  (this one looks different from the SQL Server 2008 though where in SQL Server 2008 there were ports, IP1, IP2, and so one where port *1433* was set Active)
4. SQL Server Management Studio set to use Window and SQL Server Authentication.
5. When I run NETSTAT -a on the server, I DO NOT see the line (which I think it should) like this:
   TCP ###.##.##.###:1433 ESTABLISHED.

So I am concerned that the 5 above is not showing what I am looking for.  What else can I try?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the Option for remote Connections is enabled.
Right-Click on your Server, choose Properties, Connections an dcheck the box allow remote connctions.

[image]

**Equally important!**

Make sure your Firewall allows the traffic through the Chosen Port. Also, make sure you have the rules defined in Windows Firewall or turn off Windows Firewall altogether.

Comment: @ KarmaEDV this was number 1 on my list that I have checked.
And we tried to shutdown Firewall completely but didn't make the difference.  The key is that NETSTAT -a does not show the TCP 1433 established.

Comment: can you ping the database Server from the Client Computer ? tried with dns-Name? tried with ip-address? you may also want to Setup an azure database in the cloud (for free) just to test and to see if the Clients can connect to it. You Need to set up the Firewalls on the Clients and on the Server and on the Network (routers).

Comment: I will try to ping the server from the client PC. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In the SQL Server Configuration Manager, when right mouse clicking on TCP/IP (in Protocols for MSSQLSERVER) there are two tabs.  The second tab, at the button of the list there is IPALL which was empty. Once I entered 1433 there, the SQL Server started listening on this port.  Problem Solved.